# Facebook ad tracking without noscript portion

Tags: javascript, facebook, noscript

The facebook implementation for the custom audience pixel is written in this form:

```
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
  _fbq.push(['addPixelId', '###########']);
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=###########&amp;ev=PixelInitialized" /></noscript>
```

We want to deploy this using a tag manager but ours only supports javascript only not HTML. I'm wondering how important the noscript portion of this is? Would the only drawback be that we would be just losing a certain portion of our audience, namely those on devices that do not support javascript or those who disabled javascript themselves?

Comment: Since today’s browser are usually not loading images when they are hidden using `display:none`, I wonder how effective this tracking is for non-JS clients in any case …

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. I looked around this forum and google searches after seeing that and it does seem to be a point of contention whether noscript is useful anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The noscript portion is a fallback, yes. But if you can't add it with a tag manager, why not simply place the img tag `<img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=###########&amp;ev=PixelInitialized" />` on the page somewhere, e.g. just at the bottom of the body tag.

Comment: Thanks. For context what we're trying to do is use the tag manager for this purpose as a proof of concept in order to minimize web developer effort as much as possible. Sometimes even getting a pixel added means waiting for the next release/development cycle.

Comment: Makes sense; the script portion should do the job then :)